# AppleScript to find files by exact name match from an Automator variable

Tags: applescript, snow-leopard, automator, spotlight

I have a workflow that gets the track name of a single track in my mp3 player and stores it in a variable. I then use this in the Spotlight action to find that track in my iTunes Library, but the Spotlight action gives multiple results when I want only want the exact track not all tracks that contains the name.

I need some way or a script to replace this action. All searches gives Terminal commands that I don't understand or how to use with Automator.

[image]

Here's an applescript I found that works but is really really slow, it beach-balls the Finder on every loop, Is there a way to speed this up,my library has over 10,000 tracks? thanks
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o14eb19b2459vdo/by%20default%202018-07-19%20at%20Thursday%2C%2019%20Jul%20%2017.55.18.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Please upload your Automator workflow, or post links to screenshots of it.  We need to see what you’re doing.

Comment: You look like you're running an older Mac system.  Does your version of _Automator_ have _iTunes_ actions, specifically one called _Find iTunes Tracks_ ?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, yes I'm using Snow leopard but I also have El Capitan, that iTunes action doesn't use variables either. The example given is not the worst, sometimes for a given track I'll get 6 to 10 results when the exact name of the track should give only 1 result.I'm simply trying to create a playlist from all the tracks on my mp3 player, which at the moment is 218 and all those tracks are in my library. I need to find only the the track I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have *Snow Leopard*, so I'm limited in what I can test as being viable for your system.  Therefore, please bear in mind that the following solution was devised and tested using the following:

***System info:*** *AppleScript version*: "2.7", *system version*: "10.13.5"

With that said, I see now reason that this shouldn't work on *El Capitan*.  It *might* work on *Snow Leopard*, but I'm less sure.

My proposed solution is to replace your **`Spotlight`** *Automator* action with a **`Run AppleScript`** action:

[image: Automator Workflow]

The code contained in the **`Run AppleScript`** is as follows:

```
    use framework "Foundation"
    
    property ca : a reference to current application
    
    
    on run {input, parameters}
        set MusicFolder to "/Volumes/Media/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/"
        
        set FileManager to ca's NSFileManager's defaultManager()
        set MusicFiles to (FileManager's subpathsAtPath:MusicFolder)'s ¬
            pathsMatchingExtensions:{"mp3", "m4a"}
        set [filename] to input
        set format to "SELF endswith " & ("/" & filename & ".mp3")'s quoted form & ¬
            " OR SELF endswith " & ("/" & filename & ".m4a")'s quoted form
        set filter to ca's NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:format
        
        set matches to {}
        
        repeat with match in (MusicFiles's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter) #'
            set end of matches to POSIX file (MusicFolder & match as text) as alias
        end repeat
        
        return matches
    end run
```

This will return tracks with the **exact** filename supplied by the `trackName` variable in the workflow.  Therefore, had I set `trackName` in my test run to `"Everywhere I Go"` (i.e. without the preceding `"04"`), the search would have returned an empty result.

Also, bear in mind that you may have some tracks that have identical filenames from different folders/albums.  If there are two files in different folders both called `"01 Song.mp3"`, both files will be returned in the search.